# Ruby interpolate variable in unicode string

Tags: ruby, string, unicode

To get a unicode emoticon I do:

```
irb> "\u{1f384}"
=> ""
```

but if I use a variable in the unicode I get the following error:

```
irb> d=4
=> 4
irb> "\u{1f38#{d}}"
(irb):11: unterminated Unicode escape
"\u{1f38#{d}}"
```

How to use string interpolation in unicode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pack('U')`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack) to generate Unicode data:

```
d = 4
["1f38#{d}".hex].pack("U")
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a single character from a codepoint, there's [`chr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
d = 4
(0x1f380 + d).chr('UTF-8')
#=> ""
```